# Apache Cordova Tools Installation on Visual Studio with Update 5

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013

can anyone assist me in installing Apache cordova tools in visual studio with update 5. I tried installing and it gives me an error that it requires update 4.

Answer (score 0):

Tools for Apache Cordova CTP 3.1 can only be installed on top of Visual Studio 2013 Update 4. Since you have Update 5, the installer blocks. If you want to use Tools for Apache Cordova CTP 3.1 you will need to uninstall Update 5 first.